# Don't return the lowest value if

Tags: mysql, sql

### The goal

Don't return the lowest price whose its markets are suspended.

### The problem

I don't know the syntax.

### The scenario

There is the following stored procedure to get the **lowest** and the **biggest** price of a specific product:

```
BEGIN
    Select Min(Case When product.PromotionalPrice = 0
            Then product.OriginalPrice Else
            Least(product.PromotionalPrice, product.OriginalPrice)
            End) As minProductPrice,
       Max(Case When product.PromotionalPrice = 0
            Then product.OriginalPrice Else
            Least(product.PromotionalPrice, product.OriginalPrice)
            End) As maxProductPrice
    From products As product
    Where product.Name = 'Playstation 3';
END
```

**The context is:** there are **markets** and **products**. Products belong to markets. If some market is suspended, then doesn't display its products and nor add them to max/min price comparison.

Can you all understand? *I want to exclude the products whose its markets are suspended from the `Min` or `Max` statement of above's query.*

### The tables

Here is the `markets` table:

```
+----+------+-------------+
| Id | Name | SituationId |
+----+------+-------------+
| 1  | A    | 1           |
+----+------+-------------+
| 2  | B    | 2           |
+----+------+-------------+
| 3  | C    | 3           |
+----+------+-------------+
```

Here is the `markets_situations` table:

```
+----+-----------+
| Id | Name      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Neutral   |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | Premium   |
+----+-----------+
| 3  | Suspended |
+----+-----------+
```

And finally, here is the `products` table:

```
+----+---------------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| Id | Name          | Market | PromotionalPrice | OriginalPrice |
+----+---------------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| 1  | Xbox 360      | 1      | 0                | 225,00        |
+----+---------------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| 2  | Xbox 360      | 2      | 99,00            | 175,00        |
+----+---------------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| 3  | Xbox 360      | 3      | 0                | 135,00        |
+----+---------------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| 4  | Playstation 3 | 1      | 0                | 189,00        |
+----+---------------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| 5  | Playstation 3 | 2      | 125,00           | 165,00        |
+----+---------------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| 6  | Playstation 3 | 3      | 110,00           | 185,00        |
+----+---------------+--------+------------------+---------------+
```

### To enhance the comprehension

I don't want to display `110,00` as the `Min` price of the stored procedure's result because its market (`C`) is `Suspended`.

### What I already did

I already tried the following, but without success:

```
BEGIN
    [...]

    Where product.Name = 'Playstation 3'
    And marketSituation.Id <> 3;
END
```

**What happens?** The `And` condition does nothing. The query keeps returning me the price of the suspended market.

Comment: so join the situations table and then have `where markets_situation <> 3` to filter out the suspended ones.

Comment: + **The Problem:** *I don't know the syntax.* LOL.

Comment: I already did this, @MarcB. But the query keeps returning `110,00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Min(Case When product.PromotionalPrice = 0
        Then product.OriginalPrice Else
        Least(product.PromotionalPrice, product.OriginalPrice)
        End) As minProductPrice,
   Max(Case When product.PromotionalPrice = 0
        Then product.OriginalPrice Else
        Least(product.PromotionalPrice, product.OriginalPrice)
        End) As maxProductPrice
From products As product
Inner join markets on product.market = markets.id AND markets.SituationId <> 3
Where product.Name = 'Playstation 3';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, Fabien. =)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
Select Min(Case When product.PromotionalPrice = 0
        Then product.OriginalPrice Else
        Least(product.PromotionalPrice, product.OriginalPrice)
        End) As minProductPrice,
   Max(Case When product.PromotionalPrice = 0
        Then product.OriginalPrice Else
        Least(product.PromotionalPrice, product.OriginalPrice)
        End) As maxProductPrice
From products As product INNER JOIN
Markets ON Product.Market = Markets.Id
Where product.Name = 'Playstation 3'
AND Markets.SituationID <> 3
```